# windows task scheduler - open a specific sheet on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to set up a basic task in the Windows Task Scheduler that opens a specific sheet on an Excel workbook every day - e.g. open sheet 5 on sample.xlsx.
I've managed to open the sample.xlsx file in task scheduler using the file location as argument, but it automatically opens to sheet 1 every time.

Is there an argument to automatically force Excel to open a sheet in task scheduler?

Comment: no, I don't think such option would exist.